# Running new meteorhacks/meteord application, don't have meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor, docker

I try to create a new project based on the meteor with docker.

I found the repository for this: 
https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord

I created Dockerfile and put there

```
FROM meteorhacks/meteord:onbuild
```

And then run:

```
docker run meteorhacks/meteord
docker run mongo
```

After downloading all packages so finally I run

```
docker run -i -t 807754a01782 -d 
     -e ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000 
     -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ 
     -e MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ 
     -p 8080:80  myapp
```

Based on this example:

```
docker run -d \
     -e ROOT_URL=http://yourapp.com \
     -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://url \
     -e MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://oplog_url \
     -p 8080:80 \
     yourname/app
```

Inside myapp folder, I have fresh meteor project.

But as a result, I received

```
> You don't have an meteor app to run in this image.
```

Can anyone help me and give me some clues what I'm doing wrong? Or I misunderstanding how Docker with this repository works?

EDIT:

The problem was in command correct command is:

```
docker run -d 
-e ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000 
-e MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ 
-e MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ -p 8080:80 
meteorhacks/meteord:base
```

But now when I check the status of this container I see it is excited. How Can I check what causing the problem?

Comment: What is the `807754a01782` in the `docker run` command? It has no meaning there

Comment: @Robert image id from docker  (docker images)

Comment: When you put the image name/ID, all the following arguments are part of the command/entrypoint (the position matters). You must put that ID at the end of the `docker run`, and remove "myapp". I don't know what does it there.

Comment: @Robert Thank you problem was in command correct command is: docker run -d -e ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000 -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ -e MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ -p 8080:80 meteorhacks/meteord:base but now when I try to open the web page 127.0.0.1 I cannot connect. I see container status is exited. How Can I check now what causing this problem?

Comment: Use this: `docker logs container-id`

Comment: @Robert "You don't have an meteor app to run in this image." So I back to starting point but now message is hidden in logs.

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146467/discussion-between-mateusz-and-robert).